# Need help with Magento 2 Coupon

Tags: magento2

I want to create on coupon code with these conditions but not able to do so .

Website discount need to be applied as per total cart value. 
0-299 no discount, 
above 300-499 - 10%, 
500 and above - 20%

How can I achieve this kindly help 
Thank you

Comment: You cannot achieve this via a single coupon. You need 2 of them. One for th einterval 300-499 and one for 500 and above

Answer (score 1):

You have to  create two Cart price rules:

- First, Above 300-499 - 10%
- Second 500 and above - 20%

  Goto the Admin sidebar,then  go to
- Marketing > Promotions > CartPrice Rules
- Create at rules at here
- Scroll down and expand Expansion selector the **Conditions** section
- And Click Add ,Select Cart Attribute  Subtotal and set condition 300-499 for a rule and another rule 500 .see https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/marketing/price-rule-discount-minimum-purchase.html#step-2-define-the-conditions
- Expand Expansion selector the **Actions** section and select per cent option and set 10% and 20% respectively. https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/marketing/price-rule-discount-minimum-purchase.html#step-3-define-the-actions

Answer (score 1):

As per your requirnment we have to do customization. As you know that default Magento not give this functionlity.

We have implement same customization in one of the project. From where we can give discount as per subtotal range.

here is attachment,

[image]

I have created seprate Rule for that and according to rule selection i can open custom table where we will store slab wise data and percentage.

I will guide you how you will archive this requirement.

Thanks,

Comment: Kindly suggest me how can I achieve this